# SSMS sql - Unpivoting - Values changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am a total begginer

I am trying to unpivot large dataset in `SQL Server`. I managed to make the query work, but the values are not full numbers(should be billions and I have just integers..). This is the query I am using:

```
select [Concatenated ID], dd.distributionId, cast(wartosc as float) As column1
from dbo.[To test unpivoting] [Concatenated ID] cross apply
     ( values (1-6-0-00-00, '1-6-0-00-00'), 
              (...), 
              (1-9-2-53-00, '1-9-2-53-00') 
     ) dd (wartosc, distributionId);
```

I do not know why. I tried to define the column with those values (column1) as a whole number, but seems like there is no difference.

[image]

I don't understand how this function "values" work so that the numbers are not correct?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Indeed, like Yogesh Sharma answered, one needs to add squared brackets, the values are then correct. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need square bracket inside it :

```
select [Concatenated ID], dd.distributionId, cast(wartosc as float) As column1
from dbo.[To test unpivoting] [Concatenated ID] cross apply
     ( values ([1-6-0-00-00], '1-6-0-00-00'), 
              (...), 
              ([1-9-2-53-00], '1-9-2-53-00') 
     ) dd (wartosc, distributionId);
```